# Catch all Exceptions from Android App and Send them to Server or Email

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've got an Unity app in the appstore with a couple hundred downloads now. How can I get all the exceptions that the users triggered?
Basically I want to get an email or be able to read the log from somewhere, when a user did something that triggers an exception which I caught.

Sending an email or pushing a log to a server would require extra permissions and I don't know if that's the way to go.

Kind regards

Comment: Did you release your app through **Google Play Developer Console**? If it is, you should receive crash logs under **CRASHES & ANRS** if there is one.

Comment: WTF, just use Unity's AMAZING, totally free, built-in analytics

Comment: It says "no crashes found" in that section of the GPDC. The thing is that I don't just want to get informed about crashes, but rather all events at which I am interested at. Maybe even for checking if a usually unreachable state has been reached or something.

Comment: The Event Manager in the Unity analytics seems to only show how many people have reached a certain state, like "game over", but I can't get the details of my choice for that state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `WWW` may require another permission but you need it. You can use `SystemInfo` to collect relevant system info. Also collect the exception information and store them with `WWWForm`. Send the `WWWForm` data with `WWW` to a `php` file on your server. You can read the data from `php` data and save it as a text file. You can also save it to a database then display it in an html page.

The complete example code below will collect crash log and save it as a file.

**C#**:

```
 void Start()
 {
     try
     {
         //Do Something Dangerous
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         //send log if Exception is thrown and caught
         sendLog(e);
     }
 }

 public void sendLog(Exception e)
 {
     string errorLogUrl = "http://yourServerUrl.com/gameName/log.php";
     WWWForm errorForm = new WWWForm();

     //Fill in Important Device Info
     errorForm.AddField("Device OS", SystemInfo.operatingSystem);
     errorForm.AddField("Device Model", SystemInfo.deviceModel);
     errorForm.AddField("Graphics Device Name", SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceName);
     errorForm.AddField("Graphics Device Vendor", SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceVendor);
     errorForm.AddField("Graphics Device Version", SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceVersion);
     errorForm.AddField("Graphics Memory Size", SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize);
     errorForm.AddField("System Memory Size", SystemInfo.systemMemorySize);

     //Fill in current Scene
     errorForm.AddField("Current Scene", UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

     //Fill in Important Exception Info
     errorForm.AddField("Exc-StackTrace", e.StackTrace);
     errorForm.AddField("Exc-Source", e.Source);
     errorForm.AddField("Exc-Message", e.Message);

     //FileName
     errorForm.AddField("File Name", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" + UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 900000)));

     WWW www = new WWW(errorLogUrl, errorForm);
     StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
 }

 private IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
 {
     yield return www;

     //Check if we failed to send
     if (www.error != null)
     {
         //Failed To Send.
     }
 }
```

*Not a php guru. You may have to modify the php code below.*

**PHP**:

```
<?php

        $DeviceOS = $_POST["Device OS"];
        $DeviceModel = $_POST["Device Model"];
        $GraphicsDeviceName = $_POST["Graphics Device Name"];
        $GraphicsDeviceVendor = $_POST["Graphics Device Vendor"];
        $GraphicsDeviceVersion = $_POST["Graphics Device Version"];
        $GraphicsMemorySize = $_POST["Graphics Memory Size"];
        $SystemMemorySize = $_POST["System Memory Size"];

        $CurrentScene = $_POST["Current Scene"];

        $Exc_StackTrace = $_POST["Exc-StackTrace"];
        $Exc_Source = $_POST["Exc-Source"];     
        $Exc_Message = $_POST["Exc-Message"];       

        $dump_file_name = $_POST["File Name"];

        $finalData = "Device OS: $DeviceOS";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nDevice Model: $DeviceModel";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nGraphics Device Name: $GraphicsDeviceName";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nGraphics Device Vendor: $GraphicsDeviceVendor";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nGraphics Device Version: $GraphicsDeviceVersion";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nGraphics Memory Size: $GraphicsMemorySize";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nSystem Memory Size: $SystemMemorySize";

        $finalData = "$finalData\r\n";

        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nCurrent Scene: $CurrentScene";

        $finalData = "$finalData\r\n";

        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nExc-StackTrace: $Exc_StackTrace";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nExc-Source: $Exc_Source";
        $finalData = "$finalData\r\nExc-Message: $Exc_Message";

        $myFile = $dump_file_name . ".txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh,$dump_file_name . "," . $finalData . ",");
        fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: I don't like to need that permission, but it seems to be the best way to go to actually get the variables that are interesting, thanks.

Comment: n1 really good stuff

Comment: @LumbusterTick Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are existing free services doing this, just google it.

For example Crashlytics

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics

https://fabric.io/blog/introducing-fabric-for-unity